# Wireshark: Dump client-server dialogue

Tags: wireshark

If you use "Follow TCP stream" in wireshark you get a very nice display for the client server dialogue.

One color is the client, the other color is the server.

Is there a way to dump this to a ascii without loosing who said what?

For example:

```
server> 220 "Welcome to FTP service for foo-server."
client> USER baruser
server> 331 Please specify the password.
client> supersecret
```

I want to avoid screenshots. Adding "server>" and "client>" to the lines is error prone.

Comment: Have you tried to save as cap file?

Comment: You can actually export the packet list to all kinds of formats. You could try to export it as a csv to achieve your goal

Comment: @Bas I don't see "csv" in the export list of "Follow TCP Stream" dialogue. I see ASCII, EBCDIC, Hex Dump, C Arrays, Raw. None of these formats is easy to read for the human eye. You can't see fast who (client or server) said what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may not be possible with the GUI version, but it's achievable with the [console version](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) `tshark`:

`tshark -r capture.pcap -qz follow,tcp,ascii,<stream_id> > stream.txt`

Replace `<stream_id>` with an actual stream ID (eg: `1`):

`tshark -r capture.pcap -qz follow,tcp,ascii,1 > stream.txt`

This will output an ASCII file. How is it better than saving it directly from the GUI version? Well:

- > The data sent by the second node is **prefixed with a tab** to differentiate it from the data sent by the first node.
- > Since the output in ascii mode may contain newlines, **the length of each section of output plus a newline** precedes each section of output.

This makes the file easily parsable. Example output:

```
===================================================================
Follow: tcp,ascii
Filter: tcp.stream eq 1
Node 0: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:51343
Node 1: yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:80
786
GET ...
Host: ...
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: */*
User-Agent: ...
Referer: ...
Accept-Encoding: ...
Accept-Language: ...
Cookie: ...

    235
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: ...
Expires: -1
X-Request-Guid: ...
Date: Mon, 31 Aug 2015 10:55:46 GMT
Content-Length: 0         
===================================================================
```

`786\n` is the length of the first output section from `Node 0`.
`\t235\n` is the legnth of the response section from `Node 1` and so on.

Comment: Example script based on the above, needs some patching: http://noahdavids.org/self_published/tshark-follow-stream.html

Comment: I use this: `tshark -r tmp/ftp_2015-12-16.pcap  -R ftp -tad` which does output "Request" and "Response". This way I can see clearly what was *spoken* by client and what by server.